# How Mutual authentication works

Tags: java, ssl

I have a java project that requires us to use a mutual authentication certificate. Our code is supposed to communicate with the server with a given ip address

```
socket = new Socket("00.000.000.000", 0002);
```

Since the our code is communicating with the remote system:-

1. If i create a self signed a certificate in my machine(pc) that is not connected to the internet 24/7 will mutual authentication work if i use this cert
2. If i generate a certificate using Letsencrypt, will will mutual authentication work. I plan to generate the Letsencrypt certificate in my digital ocean droplet.

Comment: Just as a sidenote: are you sure you want an octal number in the second parameter? It does not matter in this case, but once your port-numbers go beyond 8 you might be in for some surprises....

Comment: the port number is 9002 i just put zeros to not reveal the real port number. I guess the underlying issue is, will mutual authentication always work with self signed certificate signed from an ordinary pc or will it work when signed by a recognized authority.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If i create a self signed a certificate in my machine(pc) that is not connected to the internet 24/7 will mutual authentication work if i use this cert

Only if the peer trusts it. The Internet connection part is irrelevant. You will need to export your self-signed certificate to the peer and have them import it into their truststore.

> If i generate a certificate using Letsencrypt, will will mutual authentication work. I plan to generate the Letsencrypt certificate in my digital ocean droplet.

It will work if the peer's truststore trusts LetsEncrypt's certificate.

> the underlying issue is, will mutual authentication always work with self signed certificate signed from an ordinary PC

No, see above.

> or will it work when signed by a recognized authority

Yes.

In general you should avoid self-signed certificates. They aren't worth the paper they're printed on.